# is it possible to update 2 fields in the same column in one query (mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have table called '**system**' has 2 columns '**variable**' and '**value**'
with the following data:

- variable = 'username' => value = 'myuser'
- variable = 'password' => value = 'mypass'

*I want to update these 2 fields in 1 query.*

**the 2 queries are:**

```
UPDATE System SET Value = 'myuser' WHERE Variable = 'Username'
UPDATE System SET Value = 'mypass' WHERE Variable = 'Password'
```

Comment: And you want to use one query because...?

Comment: Somethins like this?

UPDATE System 
SET Value = case 
                when Variable = 'UserName' then 'myuser' 
                when Variable = 'Password' then 'mypass' 
                else Value end 
WHERE Variable in ('Username', 'Password')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE System
SET Value = (CASE
    WHEN Variable = 'Username' THEN 'myuser'
    WHEN Variable = 'Password' THEN 'mypass'
  END)
 WHERE Variable = 'Username' or Variable = 'Password'
```

Comment: @Parado . . . this is *not* it.  It doesn't have an 'else' clause so it will set all other values to `NULL`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff now its ok i think

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using he case statement:

```
UPDATE System
    SET Value = (case when Variable = 'UserName' then 'myuser'
                      when Variable = 'Password' then 'mypass'
                      else Value
                 end)
    WHERE Variable in ('Username', 'Password');
```

Comment: after using where  its necessary to use else ??

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE System 
SET Value = case when Variable = 'Username' then 'myuser' 
                 when Variable = 'Password' then 'mypass' 
            end
WHERE Variable in ('Username', 'Password')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE System SET
 Value = (case Variable when 'Username' then 'myuser' when 'Password' then 'mypass' end)
WHERE Variable  = 'Username' or Variable = 'Password'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE System SET `Value` = IF(`Variable`='Username', 'myuser', 'mypassw') 
WHERE `Value` IN ('Username', 'Password');
```